# returning [object HTMLDivElement] when using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am inserting this into my html div:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("mArray").appendChild = '<%= mArray %>'
    console.log('<%= mArray %>')

  </script>
  <div id="mArray"></div>
```

then, inside my js file, I have this:

```
var mArray = document.getElementById("mArray")
console.log("33: " + mArray)
```

but when I log it, I get this:

```
33: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

i want it to return the array data, which should look like [1,3,5,7,9]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what result do u expect?

Comment: i want it to return the array data, which should look like `[1,3,5,7,9]`

Comment: `.appendChild` is a method, hence it has to be `.appendChild(<dom node>)` and not `.appendChild = "..."` (and especially not a string)

Comment: @Andreas appreciate the response. i also had `innerHTML`, but that didn't work either, same result. So i am not necessarily sure it's that that is the issue, but maybe something else?

Comment: `.appendChild = '<%= mArray %>'` does absolutely nothing (useful). And `33: [object HTMLDivElement]` works as intended. So...

Comment: @Andreas so what would i do then so that i can output the array to an id, and then again grab it from another js file using the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading, use

```
var mArray = document.getElementById("mArray").textContent
```

and if you want to use it as a JS array (*assuming it is a valid js array format*), you could do

```
var mArrayContents = document.getElementById("mArray").textContent;
var myArray = JSON.parse( mArrayContents );
```

---

Additionally, when setting the value you do not have to use JS.
You can do it directly

```
<div id="mArray"><%= mArray %></div>
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. I eliminated the js all together, and just used your ejs example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are logging the element itself, you need to check for the data inside. Depending on how the information is stored you could possibly get the information with something such as

```
document.getElementById("mArray").innerHTML;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("mArray").value;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. i think there is another underlying issue.

Comment: let me check how to read the values of appended arrays rq this isn't something I do often